# git rebase strange confliction, there are unexcpected contend

Tags: git, conflict, rebase

I have two branches : master , joy.
there is a file named 'hello', I input command 'git rebase joy', and there is conflict, and the conflict contents is strange.

below are details by steps

- 1.

git checkout master

cat hello

show ==>

```
 Hello world
```

- 2.

git checkout joy

cat hello

show ==>

```
Hello world
one line
two line
```

- 3.

git checkout master

git rebase joy ==>

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: cherry-pick
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging hello
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in hello
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 cherry-pick
```

cat hello ==>

```
Hello world
<<<<<<< HEAD
one line
two line
=======
add one line
add 2nd line
>>>>>>> cherry- pick
```

however what I hope to find is no conflict,and the contents are

```
Hello world
one line
two line
```

- 5.

my version tree below is rather conplicated after studying

```
* <b04ea3b> 2012-06-09 [yaoyangyong]  (HEAD, joy) test rebase
* <5b595d6> 2012-06-09 [yaoyangyong]  joy clear hello
| * <eeba7d9> 2012-06-09 [yaoyangyong]  (master) clean hello
| *   <1dbc3b8> 2012-06-09 [yaoyangyong]  merge confilct
| |\  
| |/  
|/|   
| * <3cb9d88> 2012-06-09 [yaoyangyong]  modify master 1st line
* | <b1724ad> 2012-06-09 [yaoyangyong]  test merge
| *   <89a692f> 2012-06-09 [yaoyangyong]  merge from joy
| |\  
| |/  
|/|   
* | <dc96da9> 2012-06-09 [yaoyangyong]  modify second line
| *   <816f575> 2012-06-08 [yaoyangyong]  joy
| |\  
| |/  
|/|   
* | <93b5982> 2012-06-08 [yaoyangyong]  3line
| * <4400260> 2012-06-08 [yaoyangyong]  cherry-pick
* | <233d6f2> 2012-06-08 [yaoyangyong]  2nd line comment
* | <60d6edc> 2012-06-08 [yaoyangyong]  modify hello,add one line
|/  
:
* <b04ea3b> 2012-06-09 [yaoyangyong]  (HEAD, joy) test rebase
* <5b595d6> 2012-06-09 [yaoyangyong]  joy clear hello
| * <eeba7d9> 2012-06-09 [yaoyangyong]  (master) clean hello
| *   <1dbc3b8> 2012-06-09 [yaoyangyong]  merge confilct
| |\  
| |/  
|/|   
| * <3cb9d88> 2012-06-09 [yaoyangyong]  modify master 1st line
* | <b1724ad> 2012-06-09 [yaoyangyong]  test merge
| *   <89a692f> 2012-06-09 [yaoyangyong]  merge from joy
| |\  
| |/  
|/|   
* | <dc96da9> 2012-06-09 [yaoyangyong]  modify second line
| *   <816f575> 2012-06-08 [yaoyangyong]  joy
| |\  
| |/  
|/|   
* | <93b5982> 2012-06-08 [yaoyangyong]  3line
| * <4400260> 2012-06-08 [yaoyangyong]  cherry-pick
* | <233d6f2> 2012-06-08 [yaoyangyong]  2nd line comment
* | <60d6edc> 2012-06-08 [yaoyangyong]  modify hello,add one line
|/  
* <aeae413> 2012-06-08 [yaoyangyong]  add hello file
```

- 6

as a comparation , I recreate a clean folder whose version tree is very simple as below, then I do the rebase, it is successfull.

```
* <0d63388> 2012-06-09 [yaoyangyong]  (joy) add two lines
* <1f9d2f4> 2012-06-09 [yaoyangyong]  (HEAD, master) add hello file
```

Comment: You may want to set the config variable `merge.conflictstyle` to `diff3` as this will show you the hunk that came from the common base of the merge which may make it clearer where the 'conflict' is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks a little odd to me. Typically you dont ever want to rebase master. A rebase is usually done on a private branch so that when you merge it performs a fast-forward merge. Rebasing using rebase -i also gives you the opportunity to squash and fix-up commits before you merge them into the public branch (master).

I would take a look here to understand what rebasing is and does: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Using your example i would expect something like this:

### 1.

```
git checkout master
cat hello
```

shows ==>

```
Hello World
```

### 2.

```
git checkout joy
cat hello
```

shows ==>

```
Hello World
one line
two line
```

### 3.

At this point there are two commits, the first commit exists in both master and joy the second commit exists only in joy. Now we could just merge but we want to make sure the commits in joy will apply cleanly (avoiding merge commits). To do this we will rebase joy on master.

*Still operating on joy branch*

```
git rebase master
```

*Alternatively you can use interactive mode which lets you squash, fix-up, reorder, and more*

```
git rebase -i master
```

### 4.

Now that we have our joy branch looking how we want it and rebased on master, we can switch to master and just do a merge to get a nice looking history.

```
git checkout master
git merge joy
```

### 5. Important

When you do a rebase, the SHA-1 identifiers for those commits will change. Anyone who has work based on those commits will end up with a lot of nastiness to deal with as the parent of their commits no longer exists. This is why you never rebase a public branch.